# How to loop over the pages to get Table data using Selenium VBA?

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have a website with 1000's of pages and I want to extract tables from each page in single worksheet. The thing that I have tried is putting the number of pages on the loop and extracting the datas. The problem with this is that it is not automated & it extracts table data of each page in new worksheet.

What could be the **Effective solution** for this such that the table extraction of every page of the website can be done *on single sheet* without much lag as there are thousands of pages.
So my questions are:

1.How to get the the number of pages from the website so that i can use it in loop ie `For i = 1 To Numberofpages` ? OR Is there any other way other than getting number of pages *(such as Going to next page until next page does not apppear).*

2.How to put all those extracted tables from each page on single worksheet ?

- Webpage for reference:  http://www.nepalstock.com/main/floorsheet/index/1/?contract-no=&stock-symbol=&buyer=&seller=&_limit=30

```
Sub Scrape()

    Dim ResultSections As Selenium.WebElements
    Dim ResultSection As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set ch = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    ch.Start baseUrl:="http://www.nepalstock.com"
    
    For i = 1 To 3  '3 is number of pages TO BE FOUND which here is taken for Example 
      ch.Get "/main/floorsheet/index/" & i & "/?contract-no=&stock-symbol=&buyer=&seller=&_limit=30"
        Set ResultSections = ch.FindElementsByClass("my-table")
     For Each ResultSection In ResultSections
     ResultSection.AsTable.ToExcel ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Range("A1")
    Next ResultSection
    Next
    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write out to sheet you need a method to determine the last populated row, add how ever many rows gap you want, or add 1 for no gap, before writing out again.

If you don't know which column can be used to determine last row then use the first function below, if you do have a column you can rely on, then use the second function below and pass in the appropriate column number e.g. Column A would be 1.

Remember to add the required offset number to the return value:

```
Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    GetLastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long

    With ws

      GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).row

    End With

End Function
```

---

You would use as follows:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

ResultSection.AsTable.ToExcel ws.Cells(GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 2 , "A") 'leave 1 row gap before writing out next output

'ResultSection.AsTable.ToExcel ws.Cells(GetLastRow(ws) + 2, "A")  'leave 1 row gap before writing out next output
```

---

Personally, I usually prefer to populate an array with results first, then write out to sheet in one go. Given the indicated number of pages, the risk of something failing is quite high, and you haven't implemented any kind of back-off retry mechanism for getting data. Therefore, I have opted for the I/O expensive frequent writes to the worksheet during your looping.

---

**Calculate number of pages of first loaded page:**

```
Dim arr() As String

arr = Split(trim$(ch.FindElementByCss(".pager > a").text),"/")
numberOfPages = arr(ubound(arr))
```

Comment: Second function seems feasible to be so i used it but i get `Method Range of object Worksheet failed` error while running the code. Also i did not phrased the question clearly beforehand so i have edited it. Please take a look at it. *Could you also tell on how to get the number of pages from the website so that i can use it in loop?*